# AWS Cloudfront Error "IncompleteSignatureException" when accessing API Gateway Origin/Behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I am struggeling to get my AWS cloudfront/apigateway setup right. I have a cloudfront with two origins pointing to the same ApiGateway but of different routes. `/*` as default should be routed to `/dev/react` and `/api/*` should be routed to `/dev/api/` on the Apigateway. `/dev/react` is a SSR Lambda rendering a react web page and `/dev/api` are my API Lambdas. The API Lambdas are protected by the Cognito Authorizer for which I am sending the Authorization header on every request.

[image: Origins]
[image: Behaviours]

This works very well when I serve everything on the ApiGateway domain, no Auth errors or such, but when I try to serve/access it via the cloudfront I can load the react app, via the default behaviour, but when the react app calls the API endpoints I get a `IncompleteSignatureException`.

I tried forwarding the `Host` header and other things, but cannot get it to work.

I found this [ApiGateway403Erros](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/?nc1=h_ls) page where the expl. is `A request with an "Authorization" header is sent to an API resource path that doesn't exist.`, but I can pin point what that means for my scenario?

Is my routing bad? Am i missing an alias domain on the ApiGateway? What makes cloudfront not "finding" the resources on this path?

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE: I ended up with this distribution configuration ...

```yaml
Resources:
  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      Description:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - Id: Frontend
            DomainName:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
                  - .execute-api.
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - .amazonaws.com
            OriginPath: /${self:custom.stage}
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: 80
              HTTPSPort: 443
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
          - Id: Backend
            DomainName:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - 'Fn::ImportValue': 'eventkraefte-portal-backend-${self:custom.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiId'
                  - .execute-api.
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - .amazonaws.com
            OriginPath: /${self:custom.stage}
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: 80
              HTTPSPort: 443
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
        Enabled: "true"
        Comment: CDN for frontend and backend Lambdas.
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - DELETE
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            - PATCH
            - POST
            - PUT
          TargetOriginId: Frontend
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "false"
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          DefaultTTL: 1
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        CacheBehaviors:
          - PathPattern: "/api/*"
            AllowedMethods:
              - DELETE
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
              - PATCH
              - POST
              - PUT
            TargetOriginId: Backend
            ForwardedValues:
              Headers:
                - Authorization
              QueryString: "false"
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            DefaultTTL: 1
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        Aliases:
          - ${self:custom.domain}
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: ${self:custom.certificate}
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue, but I am struggling to diagnose it.

Comment: Hey, I don't remember what I did excaclty to fix this issue, but I switched from one gateway and two origins to two gatways, so each origin has its own gateway. This probably is not really the fix for this issue but worked out for me. I updated my post with my current distribution config. Maybe it helps.